# Push array into object inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, each

I'm trying to insert `<span class="">` value inside an array `arrChairs[]`, and insert this array inside an object `room{}`, obviously I'm doing it in the wrong way, because it isn't working, here are the codes:

html:

```
<div id="table">
    <a href="" id="foo1">
        <span class="chair1"></span>
        <span class="chair2"></span>
        <span class="chair3"></span>
        <span class="chair4"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="" id="foo2">
        <span class="chair1"></span>
        <span class="chair2"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="" id="foo3">
        <span class="chair1"></span>
        <span class="chair2"></span>
        <span class="chair3"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

js:

```
room = {},
arrChairs  = [];

$('#table a').each(function(i){
    tableId = $('#table a:eq('+i+')').attr('id');
    room[tableId] = {};

    $('#table a:eq('+i+') span').each(function(i){
       arrChairs.push( $(this).attr('class') ); 
    });
    room[tableId].chairs = arrChairs;
});
```

I don't know why it isn't working.

This is what `arrChair` is return me on console.log:

```
['chair1','chair2', 'chair3', 'chair4', 'chair1', 'chair2', 'chair1', 'chair2', 'chair3']
```

It's concatenating all the content. Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting `<span class="">` all together since you don't initialize `arrChairs` for each `<a>` in the root `<div>`. Try with this instead:

```
room = {};

$('#table a').each(function(i){
    tableId = $('#table a:eq('+i+')').attr('id');
    room[tableId] = {};
    var arrChairs  = [];

    $('#table a:eq('+i+') span').each(function(i){
       arrChairs.push( $(this).attr('class') ); 
    });
    room[tableId].chairs = arrChairs;
});
```

An make the `console.log` for the `room` instead of `arrChairs`.

Hope this helps